# Error while excel exporting using Django xlwt

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, xlwt

I am trying to export information to an Excel file from my web application using the xlwt library, but the following error appears in urls.py

> TypeError: export_excel_av_items() missing 1 required positional
> argument: 'request'

models.py:

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py:

```
def export_excel_av_items(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="available-items.xls"'
    wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
    ws = wb.add_sheet('Available Items')
    row_num = 0
    font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
    font_style.font.bold = True

    columns= ['Name', 'Qty']

    for col_num in range(len(columns)):
        ws.write(row_num, col_num, columns[col_num], font_style)

    font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()

    rows = Stock.objects.all().values_list(
        'name', 'quantity')

    for row in rows:
        row_num += 1

        for col_num in range(len(row)):
            ws.write(row_num, col_num, str(row[col_num]), font_style)
    wb.save(response)

    return response
```

urls.py:

```
path('', views.StockListView.as_view(), name='inventory'),
path('new', views.StockCreateView.as_view(), name='new-stock'),
path('stock/<pk>/edit', views.StockUpdateView.as_view(), name='edit-stock'),
path('stock/<pk>/delete', views.StockDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete-stock'),
path('inventory/export-excel', views.export_excel_av_items(), name='export-excel'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In URLs, you point to the function, you don't call it so the following line

```
path('inventory/export-excel', views.export_excel_av_items(), name='export-excel'),
```

shall be

```
path('inventory/export-excel', views.export_excel_av_items, name='export-excel'),
```